# Facebook Jquery ajax permission request?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, facebook

I'm am working on a facebook app where we just ask for a message in one textarea. Right now we request extended permissions directly after the user likes the page (the app is hidden until the user likes the page). We want it to be on submission of the form instead.

Is there a way to load the permissions dialog in a popup style div (not a new window...jquery.load?) and use a script page as my callback uri and post my data without reloading the tab? I've done this if with normal forms, but we need to grab the name/pic/email/bday from FB to drop into the database.

Any help, even a nudge in the right direction would be very appreciated!

/** UPDATED **/

Wanted to update with what I came up with, which uses all current SDKs. I tried to make it as template-y as possible so others can use it.

```
$("#submit").live('click',function() {
    if (someErrors === true) {
        // handle errors
    } else {
        FB.login(function(response) {
            if (response.session) {
                if (response.perms) {
                    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                        // vars: response.session.uid, response.name, response.email, response.birthday, etc
                        // serialize data here for post
                        $.post("process.php",formData,function(data) {
                            if (data.error) { 
                                // send json encoded error messages back to retrieve here like below:
                                // PHP: echo json_encode(array("error"=>"fail"));
                            } else {
                                /**
                                send data back json encoded:
                                PHP: echo json_encode(array("yourData"=>"{$yourData}","fb_id"=>"{$fb_id}","name"=>"{$name}"));
                                Now we have data like:
                                var profile = 'http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id='+data.fb_id;
                                var image = '<img src="http://graph.facebook.com/'+data.fb_id+'/picture" />';
                                var yourData = data.yourData;
                                **/
                            }
                        }, "json");
                    });
                } else {
                    // more errors
                }
            } else {
                // and more errors
            }
        }, {perms:'email,user_birthday'}); // request your specific permissions here
    }
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to do the same thing. I came up with this:

```
$("#fb_login").click(function(){

            FB.login(function(response) {
                    if (response.session) 
                    {
                        if (response.perms)
                        {
                              //alert("logged in..granted");
                             var uid = FB.getSession().uid;
                         FB.api(
                        {
                             method: 'fql.query',
                             query: 'SELECT name,email,pic FROM user WHERE uid=' + uid
                        },
                        function(response) {
                         var user = response[0];
                              $.get("addUser.php", { name: user.name, fbid: uid ,email: user.email }, function(data){
                              // ajax call to addUser.php to insert into database.


                            } );
                            }
                            );
                        } 
                        else 
                        {
                            // alert("Since You Have Not Granted Permissions For Accessing E-mails, You Can't register for any of the events.");

                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                         //alert("Not Logged In");
                    }
}, {perms:'publish_stream,email'}); // the extended permissions have to be specified here.
```

You can modify the above script to suit your changes. :)

Comment: This is almost exactly what I needed but I ended up here already. This code actually uses the REST API. I will post my code when I finish it using only the JS SDK. Thanks!

Comment: Just a quick note, no need to call `FB.getSession().uid` as the id will be in the session object: `var uid = response.session.uid;`

Answer (score 1):

Permissions dialogs need to be loaded in a popup window or in a Facebook canvas page to prevent click-jacking, so **no**, there's no way to do this (although I'd be happy to be proven wrong).

And to clarify, by popup window, I mean of the form shown in the [authentication documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/):
[image: FB auth dialog]

You **can** fire this popup when the user submits the form, like so:

```
$('#submit_btn').click(function() // could also listen to the .submit() event
{
    // show popup
    FB.login(function(response)
    {
        // use FB methods to get data you want, 
        // attach it to valid input fields

        // submit form
        $('#form').submit();
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes, I think this is the method I was looking for. Will post back and confirm when I get it working as needed. Thank you again!

Comment: I imagine it's not, but do you know if it's possible to not reload the page when someone clicks the page like button above the tab application?